# Error : Description:"Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.", Uri:""

Tags: google-apis-explorer

We use Admin Directory API services:

```
DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP, 
DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER,
DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_ORGUNIT
```

We make thousands calls to the API during the night, with .Net,

The calls work for but sometimes fails with this exception:

```
Exception: Error:"unauthorized_client", Description:"Client is 
unauthorized  to retrieve access tokens using this method.", Uri:.
```

Any idea why?

Kind regards,